# How to efficiently build a "Get descendants" algorithm in linq-to-entities?

Tags: algorithm, linq, linq-to-entities

In a tree like the one below where each item knows only its parent id and order number, what would be a good way to query all descendants of Foo?

- 1: Foo

  - 2: Child

    - 3: Grandchild 1
    - 4: Grandchild 2
- 5: Bar
- 6: Baz

I can get children like this

```
var q = from item in foos
        where item.parentid == "Foo"
        select item;
```

But how can I get all the descendants to any depth in a single query? I want to avoid recursion with multiple queries if possible. Specifically, I want to get all possible levels of descendants, not just children and grandchildren but nth level children as well. I figured I could use the order number like this case with a query like

```
var q = from item in foos
        where item.ordernumber > 1 && item.ordernumber < 5
        select item;
```

But in this case I couldn't figure out how to get the `5`, meaning the next non-descendant order number. The `1` is always known at this point.

---

**Edit:** Added forgotten detail that I want it to select all descendants, not just kids and grandkids.

Comment: im not sure i understand your question. Do you want all children of `foo`?

Comment: I want all the descendants of foo, meaning "Child, Grandchild 1 and Grandchild 2", a total of 3 items. Hope that clears up something. Fellow users, vote up the comment by @JensKloster if this is unclear and I will edit the question.

Comment: ok. could you show your classes? Does `Foo`, have a collection of `Child` or just one. Is `Foo`, `Child`, `GrandChild1` and `Grandchild2`the same type?

Comment: This is more a theoretical question about the algorithm :) I'll maby do an example later, but for now: All of them are the same type, let's say `Item`. All Items have three properties, for example `string id "Foo"`, `string parentid null` and `int ordernumber 1` or another example: `string id "Grandchild 1"`, `string parentid "Child"` and `int ordernumber 3` - no other properties at all.

Comment: It does look like this question is a little too theoretical, I'm actually thinking of removing it at this point and just settling for recursion...

Answer (score 1):

Wasn't able to find an answer on this so putting my solution here. I used a function that builds a list by calling a recursive function. The recursive function takes an id, adds the row with that ID to a list (Descendants), checks for children to that row, if there are children then it starts a foreach and calls itself for each child, passing in the id of the child:

```
    public List<WikiPageModel> Descendants;        

    public List<WikiPageModel> GetDescendantsOf(int id)
    {
        Descendants = new List<WikiPageModel>();
        GetDescendantsOf_Recursor(id);
        return Descendants;
    }

    public void GetDescendantsOf_Recursor(int id)
    {
        var page = WikiPages.FirstOrDefault(x => x.PageId == id);
        Descendants.Add(page);
        var children = GetChildrenOf(id);
        if (children.Any())
        {
            foreach (var child in children)
            {
                id = child.PageId;
                GetDescendantsOf_Recursor(id);
            }
        }
    }

    public List<WikiPageModel> GetChildrenOf(int pageId)
    {
        return WikiPages.Where(x => x.ParentPageId == pageId).ToList();
    }
```

Comment: This is what I wound up doing as well. I really wanted to avoid recursion if possible, but it seemed like the easiest option.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Element
    {
        public int ID { set; get; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public List<Element> Children { get; set; }
    }

static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<Element> elements = new List<Element>();
            Element Foo = new Element() { ID = 1, Name = "Foo" };
            Element Child = new Element() { ID = 2, Name = "Child" };
            Element GrandChild1 = new Element() { ID = 3, Name = "GrandChild 1" };
            Element GrandChild2 = new Element() { ID = 4, Name = "GrandChild 2" };
            Element Bar = new Element() { ID = 5, Name = "Bar" };
            Element Baz = new Element() { ID = 6, Name = "Baz" };
            Foo.Children = new List<Element>();
            Foo.Children.Add(Child);
            Child.Children = new List<Element>();
            Child.Children.Add(GrandChild1);
            Child.Children.Add(GrandChild2);
            elements.Add(Foo);
            elements.Add(Bar);
            elements.Add(Baz);
            var query = elements.Where(e => e.Name == "Foo").SelectMany(c => c.Children);
            var query2 = query.Union(query.SelectMany(g => g.Children));

            foreach (var item in query2)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(item.Name);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Does this method work beyond the third level? It looks to me like it would simply return the children and grandchildren, but not all nth level descendants infinitely.

Comment: Yeah, one of my requirements is getting Nth level items, which is the real problem in my question. Sorry if that was not clear. I know i can use a recursive method for that but I just want to avoid using all those throw-away contexts (I use basically 1 context per method).